# List the members of an ActiveDirectory group using Python and win32

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, active-directory

I can list the members of a Windows Active Directory group by clicking on "Network" in the Windows File Browser, then clicking "Search Active Directory," typing in the name of the group, finding it, and then paging through the names.

I would like to do the same thing from the command line using Python. I would ideally like to print the Windows username of each person, their full name, and the date that they were added to the group.

This should be possible to do, but I don't have a clue of which API to use. I would also be okay doing it from the windows command line. I do not have access to the commandline of the active directory server; I need to do this with the API. Using "wmic" has been fruitless, and the "ad" commands are not installed on my computer.